# Find strings containing English words in a text file

Tags: grep, text

Here's a sample input:

```
PAMA
Pamc
PaML
Panel00
PanelBrightnessLimits
PanelBrightnessParamsX
PanelPWMDutyRange
PanelPWMFrequency
```

I want to get:

```
Panel00
PanelBrightnessLimits
PanelBrightnessParamsX
PanelPWMDutyRange
PanelPWMFrequency
```

I.e. excluding very simple words like "a", "the", "it", "i", "ok", etc, so, let's say only English words with at least three letters in them.

Comment: `Panel`, `Bright[ness]`, `Limit[s]` are all English words. I've not mentioned or implied anywhere that there are spaces or any other symbols between them. Some strings contain spaces between words.

Comment: Do you want to find the *longest* English words though? `Pan` and `rightness` are also English words of at least three letters for example

Comment: [Look for English word in a file via terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49641)?

Comment: @don_crissti yep, that's it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "with at least 4 words", you can try this `grep`

```
$ grep -Ev '^[[:alpha:]]{,4}$' input_file
Panel00
PanelBrightnessLimits
PanelBrightnessParamsX
PanelPWMDutyRange
PanelPWMFrequency
```

Comment: I meant strings containing any English words, not only those shown in the example.